# Consume a nuget in legacy non-sdk project format with CLI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, csproj, .net-framework-version

I need to consume a nuget (created with `dotnet pack`) in some old project created with legacy non-sdk project format.

So far I see few points:

1. I can't use `dotnet add package ..` with non-sdk projects as consumers.
2. I can't use `Package Manager Console` (that consumes the nuget well) outside VS.

"Manual" adding a nuget package lines into csproj (to emulate what is done by `Package Manager Console`) like:

```
 ..
 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Binary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
       <HintPath>..\packages\Binary1.0.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Binary1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  ..
```

and then build solution doesn't seem working too. So, does anyone have any hints about proper consuming a nuget package in legacy non-sdk consumer csproj?

Comment: Projects using packages.config (rather than the newer PackageReference) has always had Visual Studio as the only officially supported way to install a package.

Comment: yeah, I'm doing some kind of automation and I need to do consuming nugets automatically in the CLI. @zivkan can you recommend something on that?

Comment: to clarify, I have VS on machine, I just can't use VS UI

Comment: if you need to be able to install any package, then my only recommendation is to use PackageReference, not packages.config. If you only need to install certain packages, and those packges don't have anything complex like web/app.config transformations, no `tools/install.ps1`, then your "manual" approach is feasible. note that packages with `content/*` files need that content copied into the project (and the files commit into source control if the packages.config and csproj are also commit).

Comment: msbuild props/targets are also a compliction. if there's `build/packageid.props` (or `.targets`, you just import that file in the csproj. But if there's `build/<tfm>/packageid.props`, then you need to do best tfm compatibility selection.

Comment: in short, you can do it if you work hard enough. But you didn't explain why you want to do this, so it could just be an XY Problem. Maybe there's a better way to solve your problem without all this complexity. For example, are you using one of the project types not compaible with PackageReference? If not, switch to PackageReference. It'll be MUCH easier then, just a single line, which you can automate with a property and a condition to make trivial to override from the CLI.

Comment: my goal is a bit tricky, I have a huge legacy set of projects that has big problems with references, so I want to resolve it just to (wisely) replace all references there on nugets, so I developed a script that parse all projects, then create appropriate nugets and now I want to consume nugets in the projects (sdk projects work fine, the problem is with non-sdk). After that I will be able to remove old references and check that it works

Comment: I can't change the actual project structure there

Comment: @dododo I posted an answer with common Nuget package usages in netframework. Do you have specific issue output? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use dotnet add package .. with non-sdk projects as consumers.

This is of course not.

[dotnet command only support .NET Core 3.1 SDK and later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet)

[image]

> I can't use Package Manager Console (that consumes the nuget well)
> outside VS.

Yes, this is the feature of VS. Outside, command and PowerShell is available.

---

The method you are using is dll reference using. From the format it seems correct. Will issue occurs during building this project?

Ensure that the `<HintPath>` is correctly relative to your project file. If the path is incorrect, the build process won't be able to find the referenced assembly. And make sure it and it's dependencies exist.

By the way, if you use some common nuget package instead of using dll directly, we always using packagereference or packages.config.

[In net framework, Default method is packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#project-type-support)

> .NET Framework projects support PackageReference, but currently
> default to packages.config. To use PackageReference, migrate the
> dependencies from packages.config into your project file, then remove
> packages.config.

Setting default package management place is here:

[image]

Package.configs always like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

And packagereference usage is like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
```

I also set this in the property group:

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

[image]

[image]

If you found something issue occurs of intellisense, please just try to build the current project. And then just check whether you can use the package.

These are the main ways to use dependencies of net framework. If there are any specific errors reported, please share them.

Comment: interesting, especially enabling `PackageReference` for .NET framework projects. Will it be possible to enable this approach for a project that already use the `packages.config` approach. Ie if I enable it, will the previous configuration based on `packages.config` work, or I will have to replace it on `PackageReference` too?